# 'else' statement not executing when it should

Tags: jquery

I have no syntax errors, nor ( can I see ) any logic errors, but the 'else' branch is not executing when it should ( I've added some alerts, to check this - but it appears the same 'if' code executes, even when the condition isn't met, i.e. on the second click of the same element)

I've tried setting up 2 separate 'if' ONLY statements, to check the only 2 alternate states of the element - basically the button text, has a + or a -  sign in front of it ...

```
$('.device').click(function(){   
var i = $('.device').index(this);    
var str = $(this).text();            
   if($('.device').index(this) === i){         
     if($(this).html("<i class='fas fa-plus'></i>                " + str)){          
       $(this).html("<i class='fas fa-minus'></i>                " + str);
       $('.main').css("visibility", "visible");
       alert("HELLO");
     }
     else{         
        $(this).html("<i class='fas fa-plus'></i>                " + str);
        $('.main').css("visibility", "hidden");
        alert("GOODBYE");
     }
   }       
  });
```

I expect, the '.main' class to alternate between hidden and visible, and the plus sign to change to a minus, or vice-versa, but it only works for the first time i.e. plus to minus, hidden to visible element ( and HELLO in the alert window every time - which suggests it is executing ONLY the 'if' branch )

Comment: The condition `if($(this).html("<i class='fas fa-plus'></i>                " + str))` will always be true. You are not checking for anything there.. It's like you are checking if the function executes..

Comment: I mean.... `$('.device').click(function () { $('.fas', this).toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus'); })`

Comment: If you provided the html it would be more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Kevin B, that looks like a better shorthand way of doing it. I'll try it now. I can't follow the logic of 'callback', because it won't always be true - it does change to 'fas fa-minus', on first click ...

Comment: Worked a treat Kevin B. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can check for class name like this

```
$('.device').click(function(){ 
    var i = $('.device').index(this); 
    var str = $(this).text(); 
    if($('.device').index(this) === i){ 
        if($(this).hasClass("fa-plus")){ 
            $(this).html("<i class='fas fa-minus'></i> " + str); 
            $('.main').css("visibility", "visible"); 
            alert("HELLO"); 
        } 
        else{ 
            $(this).html("<i class='fas fa-plus'></i> " + str); 
            $('.main').css("visibility", "hidden");
            alert("GOODBYE");
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks 'kmgt' ( reacquainting myself with JQuery - few 'teething troubles' )

Comment: My pleasure. Don't know why someone downvote this.